# Format Currency column dynamically

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following report in SSRS:

```
EmployeeNumber EmployeeName Team  Revenue
1              Jack         AA-JP €100
2              Mandy        CY-JP €150
1              David        PA-DK €300
```

The query behind is :

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 (NOLOCK)
WHERE YearNo IN (@dd_YearNo)
AND (WeekNo BETWEEN @txt_WeekNoFrom AND @txt_WeekNoTo )
AND LEFT(Team,2) IN (@dd_Group)
AND Team IN (@dd_Team)
AND SalesPerson IN(@dd_SalesPerson)
```

The parameters are the result of a query each one.
I want to format the Revenue column to set ¥ for employees who belongs to teams ending with JP
and the others will be € by default

Answer (score 0):

In the Design part of your SSRS package, right click on `Revenue` cell and go to `Text Box properties`:

[image]

Go to Number > Custom :
[image]

In the expression editor :

```
=IIF(RIGHT(Fields!Team.Value,2)="JP","¥ #,##0","€ #,##0")
```

[image]